# Is this a reasonable definition of the word 'curve' in algebraic geometry?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves

I'm trying to learn the basics of elliptic curves without having to learn schemes. However, the notion of a curve keeps throwing me. Perhaps I'm off the mark here, but it seems to be the case that algebraic geometers like to think of curves as being more than just their sets of points. In light of this, I was thinking that reasonable non-scheming definitions would be:

> **Idea.** Let $k$ denote a field. Then an *affine curve* over $k$ is a non-zero prime ideal of $k[x,y].$ And a *projective curve* over $k$ is a non-zero homogeneous ideal of $k[x,y,z].$

Is this basically correct? If not, some guidance would be nice, as I'm pretty lost.

Comment: Surely algebraic geometers have agreed upon what a curve is already...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you've defined are (irreducible) affine curves equipped with a choice of embedding into the affine plane $\mathbb{A}^2$, resp. (irreducible) projective curves equipped with a choice of embedding into the projective plane $\mathbb{P}^2$ (and your projective definition also needs a primality condition or else you allow ideals which aren't radical); (irreducible) **plane curves** for short.

(Although there's a subtlety in your definition of projective curve, which is that a morphism of projective curves is not the same thing as a graded morphism of homogeneous coordinate rings.)

Unfortunately, most curves are not plane curves: the [genus-degree formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus%E2%80%93degree_formula) implies that an irreducible projective plane curve can only have genus a triangular number $0, 1, 3, 6, \dots$, so for example no curves of genus $2$ embed in the plane. It's a nontrivial exercise using the Riemann-Roch theorem to show that every elliptic curve is a plane curve.

Algebraic geometers do indeed like to think of curves as being more than their sets of points (if by "points" you mean $k$-points); this is absolutely crucial. For example, the affine curve $x^2 + y^2 = -1$ has no real points, but it has many complex points and hence should be distinguished from the empty variety over $\mathbb{R}$.

For many purposes you can get away with thinking of a variety over $k$ in terms of its $\overline{k}$-points together with the Galois action on them. However, based on your other questions it sounds like you want to understand kernels of isogenies between elliptic curves in characteristic $p$; these kernels can be non-reduced group schemes and so you really do need to learn at least a little bit of scheme theory to understand them. So far I personally have managed to get away with thinking only in terms of functors of points and never having to learn about locally ringed spaces.

---

A definition of affine curve along the lines of what you propose is that an (irreducible) affine curve is (the Spec of) a finitely generated integral domain over $k$ with [Krull dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull_dimension) $1$. You can give an analogous definition of projective curves although you will again run into trouble when trying to define morphisms.

Anyway, if you want more help it would be helpful to be more specific about what you mean by "the notion of a curve keeps throwing me."

Answer (score 2):

To make it short, a curve is a **one dimensional variety**. As you might know, different people have different definitions of varieties. Some assume them irreducible, others don't; some assume them smooth, others don't; some assume them projective (or affine), others don't. In any case, the concept is useful in all those cases. Your definition is acceptable; but you should think that affine or projective are properties. An affine curve is a curve which is affine (i.e., an affine variety).

Answer (score 0):

A 'reasonable' definition of 'curve' should cover all the 'reasonable curves'.
The central idea of being a curve is 1-dimensional. So we fix it into the definition of 'curve' first.

We will deal with affine curve here, projective curves are similar.

Over $\mathbb{F}_p$, we would like to make $\mathbb{V}(y-x)\subset \mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{F}_p}^2$ a curve. (There is a topic about elliptic curves over $\mathbb{F}_p$). But there is a problem with $\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{F}_p}^2$, it is finite and discrete so 0-dimensional, which makes $\mathbb{V}(y-x)$ to be of dimension 0.

To make it 1-dimensional it is natural to push the verification to the algebraic closure of the base field.

Now we know that a well-defined affine curve $C$ over $k$ should at least be a 1-dimensional algebraic set in $\mathbb{A}_{\bar{k}}^n$ for some $n\geq 1$, i.e. the underlying set contains $\bar{k}$-points.

Then we should argue that if curves should be irreducible. The convention is irreducible since irreducible curves seem easier to deal with and the study of reducible cases can be reduced to the study of irreducble case. Similarly most of the definitions of varieties contain irreducibility. This is a free variable but I prefer the irreducible one.

Now we can talk about base field, i.e. a curve $C$ defined over $k$. There are two possible implications:

1. $C\subset \mathbb{A}_{\bar{k}}^n$ is the vanishing set of a set of polynomials over $k$.
2. $\mathbb{I}(C)\subset \bar{k}[x_1,...,x_n]$ is generated by a set of polynomials over $k$.

They are equivalent if $k$ is perfect, and can be different when $k$ is not perfect. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116688/the-difference-between-k-closed-variety-and-variety-defined-over-k). So the first one is actually called '$k$-closed' and the second one is called 'defined over $k$'.

Over an algebraically closed field, algebraic sets are 1-1 corresponding to radical ideals. So a curve $C$ is uniquely determined by $\mathbb{I}(C)$. Hence a natural definition should be more directly related with its vanishing ideal $\mathbb{I}(C)$. Thus we choose the second one as our definition.

In total, we find that a 'reasonable' definition of 'a curve defined over $k$' should be

> An affine curve $C$ defined over a field $k$ is a 1-dimensional irreducible algebraic set in $\mathbb{A}_{\bar{k}}^n$ for some $n\geq 1$ s.t. $\mathbb{I}(C)\subset \bar{k}[x_1,...,x_n]$ is generated by $\mathbb{I}(C)\cap k[x_1,...,x_n]$.

Projective curve can be similarly defined.

For readers who are also interested in elliptic curve, you might want to think about the definitions of nonsingular curve. The textbooks always say a curve is nonsingular if it is nonsingular on all the points. But it can mean either the $k$-rational points or $\bar{k}$-rational points.

You might wonder, with above defition of a curve defined over $k$, with at least one $k$-rational point, is it suffice to check nonsingularity on all $k$-rational points to claim it is nonsingular? The answer is no and see [this question that I asked.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3379452/can-a-singular-variety-vf-subset-bark2-be-nonsingular-on-vf-cap-k2-n/3379543#3379543)