# Universal domain in classical algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry

$\def\A{\mathbb{A}}
\def\B{\mathbb{B}}
\def\C{\mathbb{C}}
\newcommand{\Cx}{\mathbb{C}^{\times}}
\def\F{\mathbb{F}}
\def\H{\mathbb{H}}
\def\K{\mathbb{K}}
\def\M{\mathbb{M}}
\def\N{\mathbb{N}}
\def\O{\mathcal{O}}
\def\P{\mathbb{P}}
\def\Q{\mathbb{Q}}
\def\R{\mathbb{R}}
\def\T{\mathbb{T}}
\def\Z{\mathbb{Z}}$

$
\DeclareMathOperator{\trdeg}{trdeg}$

I learned the concept of a universal domain from my acquaintance some time ago. The definition is as follows:

> **Definition:** A field $\Omega$ is a **universal domain** if it
> satisfies the following two conditions:
>
> 1.$\Omega$ is algebraically closed.
>
> 2.$\F$ is a prime field of $\Omega$. $$ \trdeg_{\F} \Omega=\infty. $$

I recently learned that in classical algebraic geometry before scheme theory, one (implicitly) fixed field like this always. So I thought I should review the definition of algebraic varieties.

> **Definition:** A field $F$ is an $\Omega$ field (this is the term used only in here) if and only if it satisfies the following two
> conditions:
>
> 1.$F\subset\Omega$.
>
> 2.$$ \trdeg_{F} \Omega=\infty.$$

Now let $\A^n(\Omega):=\Omega^n$ as a set and put Zariski topology.

> **Definition:** (1) The set $V\subset \A^n(\Omega)$ is called  affine algebraic variety if it is irreducible and there exists a set $S\subset
>  \Omega[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$ consisting of some polynomials and $$
>  V=V(S):={\left\{ ( a_1,\ldots,a_n)\in \A^n(\Omega) \mathrel{} \middle|
>  \mathrel{} f(a_1,\ldots,a_n)=0\ (\forall f\in S) \right\}}$$ .
>
> (2) Let $F$ be an **$\Omega$-field**. An affine algebraic variety
> $V\subset \A^n(\Omega)$ is called (defined) over $F$ if there exists a
> set $T\subset F[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$ consisting of some polynomials and
> $$I(V):={\left\{ f\in\Omega[X_1,\ldots,X_n] \mathrel{} \middle|
>  \mathrel{} f(a_1,\ldots,a_n)=0\ (\forall (a_1,\ldots,a_n)\in V)
>  \right\}}
>  =\sum_{f\in T}\Omega[X_1,\ldots,X_n]f $$ (i.e., when $I(V)$ is an ideal generated by $T$). This state is written as $V/F$.

**Note**: This is equivalent to $V=V(U)$ with some $U\subset F[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$ when $F$ is a **perfect field** ([details](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116688/the-difference-between-k-closed-variety-and-variety-defined-over-k)).

Similarly, if we discuss $\P^n(\Omega)$ by replacing the polynomial with a homogeneous polynomial, we obtain the definition of a projective algebraic variety.

After some investigation, I found that people implicitly use the following main principle:

> **Principle in classical algebraic geometry:** In classical algebraic geometry, one always fixes an universal domain $\Omega$ before
> starting a discussion, and all fields are considered to be $\Omega$
> fields unless otherwise specified. And if necessary, the universal
> domain is replaced appropriately (e.g., when changing the field of
> characteristics).

So, for example, to be really strict,since the algebraic group $GL_n:=GL_n(\Omega)$ depends on $\Omega$, when considered on $\C$ and when considered on $\F_q$ they are different as sets.

**Question:**

0. Are the above definitions standard and correct?
1. Why do the universal domain and $\Omega$-field need the assumption on the transcendental degree? For example, when considering an algebraic variety defined on an algebraic number field, is there any inconvenience if we develop classical algebraic geometry based on $\bar{\Q}$?
2. When should I change $\Omega$ to what kind of fields? Please tell me concretly. Cases such as $F=\Q,\C,\F_q,\C(t),\F_q(t)$ come to mind immediately.
3. If the above "Principle in classical algebraic geometry" is correct, why don't most authors except Weil write this? Why don't they introduce universal domain?

Comment: I cannot stress enough that essentially nobody uses this and nobody *wants* to use this. The concept of a universal domain was a hack by Weil to do algebraic geometry in a systematic way over non-algebraically closed fields before schemes were invented/discovered; it has been entirely supplanted by schemes and almost everyone tries as hard as they can to avoid using it. See for instance Brian Conrad's assertion that ["nobody should ever again have to read Weil's 'Foundations of algebraic geometry'"](http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/).

Comment: Nobody writes about classical algebraic geometry anymore except as an introduction. To handle what Weil was trying to do, they move onto scheme theory, which I suggest you do as well.

Comment: I fully expected such comments. What I wanted to make sure of here is that even if it is only used as an introduction, it should be properly developed if it is introduced. And, theoretical neatness aside, (non-schematic) algebraic varieties themselves seem to be widely used in practice. In that sense, I think it is worthwhile to study it thoroughly.

Comment: I found a opinion such like second answer of https://mathoverflow.net/questions/36979/some-arithmetic-terminology-universal-domain-specialization-chow-point

Comment: Nobody writes this stuff in the introduction to their books - the "classical algebraic geometry" which forms most introductions is pure variety-theoretic stuff where an affine variety is a Zariski-closed subset of $k^n$ for an algebraically closed field $k$. Universal domains are not mentioned as an intro in any book I've encountered - where are you seeing this?

Comment: @KReiser Perhaps you should tell that to the model theorists – they still like thinking about saturated models of first-order theories, such as universal domains! (Model theory might well be revolutionised if someone could figure out how to do schemes, or at least schemes of finite presentation, over not just algebraically closed fields but more general first-order theories.)

Comment: @ZhenLin Interesting - my advisor was partially in model theory (o-minimal stuff, etc) and I never heard about this. (But yes, I see your point, "nobody" is perhaps slightly hyperbolic.)

Comment: @ZhenLin where are you seeing non-schematic varieties used in practice? Perhaps there are papers out there that only use basic polynomial algebra, but I think you will find that "variety over $k$" is always ultimately referring to an integral (occasionally just reduced), separated scheme of finite type over $k$. I have also never seen a paper from the post-EGA era that invokes things like systematic passage to radical ideals.

Comment: @TabesBridges I am referring to the notion that model theory is algebraic geometry minus fields. Starting from a structure $A$ one can build a kind of superstructure (I forget the word the model theorists use) comprising not just the elements of $A$ but also the definable subsets of $A^n$ (for all finite $n$) modulo definable relations, etc. etc. If $A$ is an algebraically closed field then this superstructure includes all classical varieties and much more besides. But $A$ could be something else entirely... say, a dense linear order.

Comment: @ZhenLin Honestly, as a model theorist, I'm a little curious what that would look like. From the little algebraic geometry I do know it doesn't seem like a lot of the machinery of schemes meaningfully generalizes to the contexts model theorists look at. What would one be looking for in such a generalization?